# Store encrypted data in XML

Tags: java, xml, encryption

## Context

I work in the energy domain with devices that send data in clear text over some medium, that finally ends on a computer. The data is there decoded and stored in XML files.

A current XML file storing data for a device looks like this at the moment:

```
<Device>
    <Address>1234</Address>
    <SomeOtherParam />
    <Data>
        <Record>
            <Key name="Energy" ... />
            <Value unit="kWh">42.56</Value>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <Key name="Volume" ... />
            <Value unit="m3">2.317</Value>
        </Record>
        ...
    </Data>
</Device>
```

## Change

Now, with the emergence of IoT, new devices must send some parts of their data **encrypted** (some parts can still remain unencrypted though). When the data reaches the computer, it's possible (but not mandatory) that the data is still encrypted and could not be decrypted at this moment. However, I still need to save it in XML for a further decryption but the actual XML structure wasn't designed to store encrypted data.

## Imagined solutions

Solution 1

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <Key name="Volume" ... />
        <Value unit="m3">2.317</Value>
    </Record>
    ...
    <EncryptedRecords>4F2B8678...</EncryptedRecords>
</Data>
```

Solution 2

```
<Data>
    <Decrypted>
        <Record>
            <Key name="Volume" ... />
            <Value unit="m3">2.317</Value>
        </Record>
        ...
    </Decrypted>
    <Encrypted>
        ???
    </Encrypted>
</Data>
```

Solution 3

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <Key name="Volume" ... />
        <Value unit="m3">2.317</Value>
    </Record>
    ...
</Data>
<EncryptedData>
    ???
</EncryptedData>
```

Personal thoughts

- Solution 1: could provide a minimalist working solution
- Solution 2: could possibly break backward-compatibility
- Solution 3: what should replace `???` ?

## Question

What would be the *ideal* evolution of the XML's structure to store the encrypted data (keep in mind that I need to keep backward-compatibility) ?

I also found that the W3C has already [published](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/) a recommendation long time ago. Should I stick to this instead ? Basically, it means `???` of solution 3 could be filled with a recommended structure.

Precision: these XML files are manipulated with JAXB. If JAXB has any facilitation with encryption, it could be an advantage if the new XML structure is directly supported.

Comment: What specifically is your requirement however?  If it merely needs to be encrypted on transport, then you could potentially solve this problem with few application changes.  Otherwise if the data must be encrypted on the device and/or stored in a backend system in an encrypted manner then it certainly becomes more complicated.  Furthermore, how is this data being transported?  What protocol and medium is being used?

Comment: Encryption without authentication is useless. XML encryption is tricky. Please have a look at IT Security SE for leads.

Answer (score 1):

One possible suggestion: Add an attribute to any XML tag.

```
<Record Encrypted="true">ABNSDJDFGHD</Record>
```

Then when reading you can still read the tag and based on the attribute call an additional function to decrypt the data.  The Encrypted attribute could be added to any tag.  Your current XML structure would remain the same.

Comment: For more general use, I would suggest instead an `encryptedWith` attribute that could identify the encryption type. You could use values like "AES" or "Blowfish", or internal identifiers if you don't want to identify the algorithm used.

Comment: The problem is that records aren't encrypted one by one but as a whole. Therefore I could only store one encrypted block containing many records, which is semantically speaking different from a single record.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion based on your description that your device is using [Wireless Meter Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter-Bus) over radio that a simple solution involving secure transport is probably going to be more trouble than it is worth.  It appears that in M-Bus (being wholly unfamiliar with it mind you) that it is flexible such that you could feasibly define your own Transport layer thus implementing something like [Transmission Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is TECHNICALLY feasible.  I have no idea if this even exists however and it certainly wouldn't be worth implementing all of that just to use something readily available like SSL certificates and handshakes to make sure data is sent securely from client to device.

You mention that you are using JAXB so I assume you have a Java program that can marshall, unmarshall XML via annotations.  The [Jasypt Framework](http://www.jasypt.org/jaxb.html) integrates nicely with JAXB to achieve encryption and decryption of specific fields through the use of adapters.

To be honest though, I am surprised that your device is not only running Java, but has enough computing resources to handle an operating system, the overhead of large Java frameworks like JAXB, and can afford to communicate in verbose XML data.  My answer fully assumes that both the device sending the data, as well as the device receiving the data are both running Java programs with sufficient computing resources available to them in an OS that is capable of this.

Comment: The device isn't running Java (the firmware is basically written in C), but it isn't the point of interest of my question. The problem I have is on the "server" side, which is a Java program that should handle (decode, decrypt, store, etc.) incoming data from many of these devices.

Comment: My answer doesn't fundamentally change then.  You can still use JAXB with Jasypt to decrypt any fields that are encrypted.  I am still confused though as to HOW the data fields are being encrypted?  The device firmware would have to be updated to use encryption keys to encrypt the data.  Those keys would need to be available on the Java program to decrypt the data.

Comment: Indeed, the firmware knows the key to encrypt the data. But the key is not always known by the Java program. In this case the best I could do is to store the data encrypted. My problem is more: *What's the best way to store the encrypted data in xml ?* rather than *How to decrypt the encrypted data from an xml ?*

Comment: By the way, thank you for having mentionned Jasypt Framework. This could be helpful for me in the future.

Comment: @Spotted Just store it as is :)  You probably want to make sure you have some way to identify the record to a specific device, or else you may not know how to retrieve the decryption key at a later date.  There is no problem to store an XML document in a database that has encrypted fields as long as you have some uniquely identifiable fields in that record that can link it directly or indirectly to a specific device or encryption key

Comment: I think it's not that easy to just store it "as is", see my comment on Jon Raynor's answer. Also pay attention to solution 1, where I wrote EncryptedRecord**s**

Comment: @Spotted I don't understand.  Is the ENTIRE XML document encrypted from the device?  Is the device giving you a block of encrypted data that represents potentially multiple XML documents and records?

Comment: The device only sends me bytes. A part of these bytes are actually encrypted data. This encrypted block represents potentially multiple records.

Comment: @Spotted I understand now.  The core problem you have is that if you actually do not have the decryption keys in the Java side then what else could you do but store EncryptedData in the database?  All of your suggested solutions are essentially exactly the same.  The only thing I caution you about is to have a additional data points that would allow a different process to determine the encryption algorithm used, and to indirectly find out what decryption key can be used.

Comment: You got it. :-) Would you recommend me to create this "additonnal data point" in a custom way (like 1 of my 3 solution) or like the W3C recommends it ?

Comment: @Spotted I would do it in your own way but use the W3C recommendation for guidance.  When it comes to standards you are best to go all-in rather than adopt just certain pieces and parts.